# Проблемы с программой

Tags: c++, ооп

Конструктор игнорирует 2 метода в конце, поэтому переменные зарплаты и премии не высчитываются(этим и должны заняться 2 игнорируемых метода); так же метод toFile вроде бы работает, fout.is_open() показывает, что файл открыт, но изменений никаких в файле не происходит. В чём может быть проблема?

```
//Описать Класс Работник
    #include<iostream>
    #include<string>
    #include<fstream>
    using namespace std;


    class worker
    {

        string name;
        int experience;
        int hourlyWag;
        int workedHours;
        int salary;
        double premy;

        void salaryCalculate()
        {
            salary = workedHours * hourlyWag;
        }

        void premyCalculate()
        {
            if (experience < 1) { premy = 0; return; }
            if (experience < 3) { premy = (double) (salary * 0.05); return; }
            if (experience < 5) { premy = (double)((salary / 100) * 8); return; }
            premy = (double)((salary / 100) * 15); return;
        }

    public:

        worker()
        {
            cout << "Enter worker's name: ";
            cin >> name; cout << endl;
            cout << "Enter worker's experience: ";
            cin >> experience; cout << endl;
            cout << "Enter worker's hourly wag: ";
            cin >> hourlyWag; cout << endl;
            cout << "Enter how much hours "<<name<<" has worked: ";
            cin >> workedHours; cout << endl;


            void salaryCalculate();
            void premyCalculate();
        }

        void Display()
        {
            cout << name << endl
                << "Experience is " << experience << endl
                << "Hourly wage is " << hourlyWag << endl
                << "Denis has worked " << workedHours << " hours" << endl
                << "Salary is " << salary << endl
                << "Premy is " << premy << endl;
        }

        void toFile()
        {
            ofstream fout;
            fout.open("A:\ProgProjects\output.txt");
            fout << name << endl
                << "Experience is " << experience << endl
                << "Hourly wage is " << hourlyWag << endl
                << "Denis has worked " << workedHours << " hours" << endl
                << "Salary is " << salary << endl
                << "Premy is " << premy << endl;
            fout.close();
            cout << "Information about " << name << " was written in file output.txt"<<endl<<endl;

        }
    };



    int main()
    {
        worker a;

        a.Display();
        a.toFile();

        return 0;



    }
```

Comment: Хардкорная копипаста? `void salaryCalculate();` - это объявление функции, а вызов `salaryCalculate();`. `fin.is_open() показывает, что файл открыт` - в приведенном коде ничего такого нет, а путь к файлу неправильный

Comment: @VTT Почему считаете путь неправильным? Вдруг у человека дискета вставлена?

Comment: @V-Mor Потому что `\P` и `\o` являются невалидными управляющими последовательностями.

Comment: @VTT Ах да, точно, забыл.

Answer (score 2):

Не нашёл `fin` в представленном коде, вследствие чего могу сказать лишь, что изменения в файл записываются после его закрытия. Если файл открыт на запись, записанная в него информация не отобразится до тех пор, пока он не будет закрыт.

`void salaryCalculate();` – объявление функции, а не её вызов, как уже сказали в комментарии. Используйте просто `salaryCalculate();`. Для второго метода аналогично.

Comment: Может, *"Используйте просто `salaryCalculate();`"*? без void?

Comment: @Harry Упс, спасибо, исправил.

Comment: Похоже уже мозги кипят:) С вызовами функций протупил, но вопрос с txt файлом остаётся открытым, в описании я перепутал, я проверял fout.is_open(); путь файла правильный, но всё равно не записывает почему-то(

Comment: вопрос решил, слеши не в ту сторону:) (А в проводнике почему то именно в эту сторону показывает)

Comment: @Drewdzzz Как слеши помогли решить проблему с неправильно использованными методами?